# How do i resolve this Flask-WTF issue: Jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField object' has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am relatively new to coding so I apologize for any vagueness or error. Please do correct me. I have been following Corey Schafers Flask Tutorial and on part 3 I've been stuck with the following error: Jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField object' has no attribute 'label', while trying to run the following registration page:

**register.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form().hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Additional Involved files:**

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

**flaskblog.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
...
@app.route('/register')
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm
    return render_template('register.html', title='register', form=form)
```

**This is the traceback from the server:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\flask_blog.py", line 39, in register
    return render_template('register.html', title='register', form=form)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\templates\register.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\templates\layout.html", line 47, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  File "C:\Users\Musa\Desktop\Flask_Blog\templates\register.html", line 9, in block "content"
    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField object' has no attribute 'label'
```

How do I approach resolving this issue? I tried looking at the WTForms Documentation and it said that:

"_If _form and _name isn’t provided, an UnboundField will be returned instead. Call its bind() method with a form instance and a name to construct the field."

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields/#wtforms.fields.Label

So I Know that label attribute is not receiving a form or a name but then what is form-control doing?
I don't know how to make sense of this. 
I tried proofreading the code on Corey Schafer's git folder but still to no avail:
https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/03-Forms-and-Validation
please do help!

Answer (score 4):

In your flaskblog.py you assign **class** RegistrationForm as variable form. Not **instance**. This adding parenthesis should fix it.

```
@app.route('/register')
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm() # Added parenthesis here. 
    return render_template('register.html', title='register', form=form)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this but now i  have another error:TypeError: 'RegistrationForm' object is not callable

Comment: Interesting. In your code example there is three dots `...` between import and `@app.route('/register')`-lines.  Is RegistrationForm mentioned in there somewhere? It sounds that you've defined it earlier and it isn't anymore something you've imported.

Comment: Does your Login form work? Or any other form you have created with wtf_forms?

Comment: I did not call on the RegistrationForm earlier. I left it out for i felt it wasn't related but here it is:
 {
  'author':"Johnny Hendrix",
  'title':"The G String",
  'content':"6th-5th-1st string",
  'date_posted':"April 15,2020"


 },
 {
  'author':"Pablo Escobar",
  'title':"Negocio101",
  'content': "No usas su producto.",
  'date_posted':"April 20,2020"

 }
]

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
@app.route('/about')
def about_me():
 return render_template('about.html', title='About')

Comment: Sorry that it isn't formatted, but you can still discern RegistrationForm was not called.

Comment: I haven't updated the login.html page because in the tutorial. Schafer worked on and then inspected the Register page first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Very interesting. Here is conversation about very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820081/flask-attributeerror-unboundfield-object-has-no-attribute-call .  But not exactly the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your input. You were right about turning RegistrationForm into an instance in flask_blog.py like so: form = RegistrationForm().                             
The reason why I was still getting an error was because of line 6 of register.html I had  made a form object  so i changed it to this  {{ form.hidden_tag() }} and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error.
You just need to initialize the `form = RegistrationForm` line in "flaskblog.py" with a paranthesis "()" at the end.

Here is a working code:

```
@app.route('/register')
def register():
form = RegistrationForm() # <--- Paranthesis Added
return render_template('register.html', title='register', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

you need to inherit from FlaskForm when defining your class

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):

else you will get the error mentioned